# Is there a way to open the task bar programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ios

Can the task bar be opened programmatically? I mean the one when you double tap the home button where you can close background apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its called the multitasking bar .. and simply No you can't do this.

Answer (score 0):

You cant make a running application quit to back ground, make back ground running App to fore ground and Display the Task bar programatically.